# Why is the 3rd parameter needed in iterator_apply example

Tags: php

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-apply.php

I can't understand from the documentation why the 3rd parameter, i.e. array($it), is needed in the example below.

```
function print_caps(Iterator $iterator) {
    echo strtoupper($iterator->current()) . "\n";
    return TRUE;
}

$it = new ArrayIterator(array("Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries"));
iterator_apply($it, "print_caps", array($it));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the second parameter (the callback), the manual says:

> This function only receives the given args, so it is nullary by default.

This is a rather awkward way of saying that by default (i.e. if there is no third parameter), the callback will be called with no arguments.

In other words, this:

```
iterator_apply($some_iterator, $some_callback);
```

Is roughly equivalent to this:

```
foreach ( $some_iterator as $value ) {
    $some_callback();
}
```

Since the callback is not passed any arguments, it can't see the iterator, or the current value.

If instead you pass the third value, the function is called with those arguments each time, so:

```
iterator_apply($some_iterator, $some_callback, [1,2,3]);
```

Is roughly equivalent to this:

```
foreach ( $some_iterator as $value ) {
    $some_callback(1,2,3);
}
```

The example you are looking at therefore allows the callback to see the iterator each time it is called, by passing it as the parameter to the callback; that is:

```
iterator_apply($some_iterator, $some_callback, [$some_iterator]);
```

Is roughly equivalent to this:

```
foreach ( $some_iterator as $value ) {
    $some_callback($some_iterator);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was unclear to me that the first argument and 3rd need not necessarily be related.